# How to propedit svn externals?

Tags: svn

I feel as if the answer to the question is stupidly simple but I can't seem to find anything out there and I'm not yet overly experienced with SVN.

This is the propset command I used to make it:

`svn propset svn:externals "wp-content http://example.com" .`

I know there is a `propedit` but I'm not sure how it is used in conjunction with svn externals. Is it possible to edit the location to lets say http://example.com/branches/example?

Thank you very much for any advice.

Answer (score 7):

`propedit` will open a external editor (vim, emacs, etc) to edit your svn properties. I've been using it for `svn:externals` with `emacs` because it is a multi lines property.

```
svn pe svn:externals . --editor-cmd emacs
```

Answer (score 0):

```
svn propedit svn:externals --editor-cmd "(echo http://lssvn:3380/svn/ls/releases/16.43.00 p & echo http://lssvn:3380/svn/ls/releases/16.43.00 a & echo http://lssvn:3380/svn/ls/releases/16.43.00 t) >" http://lssvn:3380/svn/ls/sandbox/dwe/externals_test -m "LX-0 Message"
```

Answer (score -1):

From `svn help pe`

> propedit PROPNAME TARGET

i.e., in your case `svn pe svn:externals .` and in default $EDITOR you'll get window with property-values (because it can be multiline). Edit and save changes

But for pure replacement new non-interactive propset (with new value) *may* be better

Comment: Like I said up there... `I know there is a propedit but I'm not sure how it is used in conjunction with svn externals` and `I can't seem to find anything out there`. Please read first.

Comment: svn:externals is **ordinary** Subversion-property with **common** rules. SVN Book is your best friend

Comment: The only thing that's common with svn:externals (that I could find) is `propset`. I realize why you are pushing the book, which is fine, but I was in a jam and was asking for *help* as I couldn't find anything. P.s. You really need to stop and think from time to time... this is a place for help after all. P.p.s. The downvote did not come from me.